Operator norm of $A^2B$ versus $ABA$
Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric, positive, invertible matrices. My end goal is to show that $\|A^2B\| = \|ABA\|$ in operator norm.
I initially thought it could be proved as follows. By definition of similar matrices, $ABA$ is similar to $J^{-1}ABAJ$ for any invertible matrix $J$.
Therefore, taking $J = A^{-1}$ we obtain that $ABA$ is similar to $AABAA^{-1} = A^2B$. Thus, $A^2B$ has the same eigenvalues as $ABA$. However, this does not directly imply that they have the same operator norm.
If true, how could I show that $\|A^2B\| = \|ABA\|$? If not true, is there any hope to get an inequality of the form $\|A^2B\| \leq \|ABA\|$?
Edit 1: the operator norm here is defined as
$$\|A\| = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\| A x\| _2}{\|x\|_2} = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}\left(A^T A\right)},
$$
with $\|\cdot\|_2$ the Euclidean norm.
Edit 2: following the provided counter-example below it is clear that we do not always have $\|A^2B\| = \|ABA\|$. However, we always have $\|ABA\| \leq \|A^2B\|$. Indeed, we have
$$\|ABA\| = \lambda_{\max}(ABA) = \lambda_{\max}(A^2B) \leq \|A^2B\|,$$
where the first equality follows from $ABA$ being positive and the second equality from the fact that $A^2B$ has the same eigenvalues as $ABA$. $\lambda_{\max}$ denotes the largest eigenvalue in absolute value.

The inequality is false. It should be easy to generate a random counterexample.

It seems that the reverse inequality holds, see my comment below.

Here is an example where $A,B$ is not invertible, where one can see what happens. Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\|A^2B\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|=\sqrt2,
\qquad
\|ABA\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|=1.
$$
For an actual example, take
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\|A^2B\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\4&8\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|=\sqrt{41+3\sqrt{185}}\simeq9.04
$$
while
$$
\|ABA\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&8\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|=\frac{9+\sqrt{65}}2\simeq 8.53.
$$
If we reverse roles,
$$
\|B^2A\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}2&6\\3&10\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|=\sqrt{\frac{149+3\sqrt{2465}}2}\simeq 12.21,
$$
while
$$
\|BAB\|=\Bigg\|\begin{bmatrix}3&5\\5&9\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\|=6+\sqrt{34}\simeq11.83 .
$$

Edit: As DimSum has cleverly noticed, since $ABA$ is similar to $A^2B$, and $ABA$ is positive,  we have
$$
\|ABA\|=\lambda_\max(ABA)=\lambda_\max(A^2B)\leq\|A^2B\|. 
$$

I think the computations are off. In your example with invertible matrices I get that $|A^2B|| \simeq 9.06$ and  $|ABA|| \simeq 8.54$. Which norm are you computing? For $|B^2A|$ and $|BAB|$ the computations are correct. After update I will accept the answer

In fact, it seems that we always have $|ABA| \leq |A^2B|$. Indeed, we have
$$|ABA| = \lambda_{\max}(ABA) = \lambda_{\max}(A^2B) \leq |A^2B|,$$
where the first equality follows from $ABA$ being positive and the second equality from the fact that $A^2B$ has the same eigenvalues as $ABA$.

I shouldn't type answers from the phone. I edited the correct values. Nice idea for the inequality.
